# Why am I receiving a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

The problem I am working on is asking me to modify existing code as follows:

> The following program uses a list to store a user-entered set of resistance values and computes I. Modify the program to compute the voltage drop across each resistor, store each in another list voltage_drop, and finally print the results in the specified format.

Here is the code without my modifications:

```
resistors = []
voltage_drop = []

print( '%d resistors are in series.' % num_resistors)
print('This program calculates the'),
print('voltage drop across each resistor.')

input_voltage = float(input('Input voltage applied to circuit: '))
print (input_voltage)

print('Input ohms of {} resistors'.format(num_resistors))
for i in range(num_resistors):
    res = float(input('{})'.format(i + 1)))
    print(res)
    resistors.append(res)

#  Calculate current
current = input_voltage / sum(resistors)

# Calculate voltage drop over each resistor
# ...

# Print the voltage drop per resistor
# ...
```

Here is the code with my modifications:

```
resistors = []
voltage_drop = []

print( '%d resistors are in series.' % num_resistors)
print('This program calculates the'),
print('voltage drop across each resistor.')

input_voltage = float(input('Input voltage applied to circuit: '))
print (input_voltage)

print('Input ohms of {} resistors'.format(num_resistors))
for i in range(num_resistors):
    res = float(input('{})'.format(i + 1)))
    print(res)
    resistors.append(res)

#  Calculate current
current = input_voltage / sum(resistors)

# Calculate voltage drop over each resistor
for res in resistors:
    vol_drop = current * res
    voltage_drop.append(vol_drop)

# Print the voltage drop per resistor

print('Voltage drop per resistor is')
for voldrop in voltage_drop:
    print('{}) {:.2f} V'.format(voltage_drop.index(voldrop), voldrop)
```

If I comment out the last three lines or change it to only print the drop in voltage, it works just fine. It's supposed to print like

1. first number
2. second number
   and so on.

Here is the error I am receiving:

File "main.py", line 31

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Post complete error message

Comment: Count your parentheses…

Comment: @Sociopath That is the complete error message. It's a homework problem through zyBooks and that's all it gave me.

Comment: @deceze It would be something that simple. Thank you, still relatively new so I was stumped!

Comment: @mo-mouse I don't know where you write your code but I would recommend using an IDE to avoid these kind of mistakes. Most IDEs close the brackets automatically for you. Pycharm is an example of a popular one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print statement is missing a closing ')':

```
 print('{}) {:.2f} V'.format(voltage_drop.index(voldrop), voldrop)
```

indicated by the "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"